# How do I assert on a ServerResponse body?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Suppose I write a test for some [handler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-functional.html). I'm likely to assert on the response status and response body. Here's how I do it:

```java
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;

// ...

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "DataFlowIssue" /* because getField() is @Nullable */})
    private void responseChecksOut(ServerResponse response, HttpStatus expectedStatus, String expectedBody) {
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(expectedStatus);

            Mono<String> body = (Mono<String>) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(response, "entity");
            StepVerifier.create(body)
                    .expectNext(expectedBody)
                    .verifyComplete();
        });
    }
```

It's not pretty and requires as much as two suppressions. Besides, it relies on my knowledge of the internals of a specific `ServerResponse` implementation, `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder.DefaultEntityResponse` (a nested private class). As I understood, `EntityResponse` is a `ServerResponse` that has a body. That body is stored as a field of generic type `T` which is named `entity`. Which is in my case `Mono<String>`

And it's all because `ServerResponse` doesn't expose a `getBody()` method

What are better ways to do it? Criteria (try to check as many of these as you can):

1. No suppressions
2. No reflective digging
3. Implementation-agnostic

## UPD

I tried to play by Spring's rules, here's where it got me

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
    private void responseChecksOut(ServerResponse response, HttpStatus expectedStatus, String expectedBody) {
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(expectedStatus);

            MockServerWebExchange exchange =
                    MockServerWebExchange.builder(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/")).build();
            Mono<Void> mono = response.writeTo(exchange, new ServerResponse.Context() {
                @Override
                @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
                public List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> messageWriters() {
                    return List.of(new HttpMessageWriter<>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<MediaType> getWritableMediaTypes() {
                            return Collections.emptyList();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean canWrite(ResolvableType elementType, MediaType mediaType) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Mono<Void> write(Publisher<?> inputStream, ResolvableType elementType,
                                                MediaType mediaType, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage message,
                                                Map<String, Object> hints) {
                            inputStream.subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<Object>() {
                                @Override
                                protected void hookOnNext(Object value) {
                                    message.writeWith(Mono.just(DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance
                                                    .wrap(String.valueOf(value).getBytes())))
                                            .subscribe();
                                }
                            });
                            return Mono.empty();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
                public List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers() {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
            });
            StepVerifier.create(mono)
                    .verifyComplete();
            StepVerifier.create(exchange.getResponse().getBodyAsString())
                    .expectNext(expectedBody)
                    .verifyComplete();
        });
    }
```

In case you're interested, it works, but I'd rather shoot myself then commit that code