# Is it possible to implement ServerResponse.Context interface?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

***Note.** This question is related to [this earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78054404/how-do-i-assert-on-a-serverresponse-body)*

Look, this is bizarre

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import java.util.List;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<SomeInterface<?>> someInterfaces = List.of(
                new SomeInterface<>() {
                    @Override
                    public void someMethod(Publisher<?> somePublisher) {
                        // doesn't compile because "Cannot resolve method 'println(<lambda parameter>)'"
                        somePublisher.subscribe(e -> System.out.println(e));
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    interface SomeInterface<T> {
        void someMethod(Publisher<? extends T> somePublisher);
    }
}
```

It's mind-boggling for two reasons:

1. Javac *still* doesn't know that everything in Java is an `Object`, even "lambda parameter" (does it ever learn)
2. Spring expects me to implement a similar interface (which appears impossible)

Let me describe it in more detail

Suppose I have a `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse`

```java
Mono<ServerResponse> response = ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK).bodyValue(Mono.just("12345"));
```

and I want to check its body in a unit test. I can't just call some `getBody()`! There's s no such thing in the API. However, I can `writeTo()` a `ServerWebExchange`. Provided I pass a `ServerResponse.Context`

```java
// here it is
    interface Context {

        List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> messageWriters();

        List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers();
    }
```

So I need to implement a `messageWriters()` method that returns a `List` of `HttpMessageWriter`s. An `HttpMessageWriter` is expected to transfer data from a `Publisher` (in my case a `Mono` of "12345") to a `ReactiveHttpOutputMessage` (in my case it's `ServerWebExchange`'s response)

```java
// it's all you need to know about the interface

public interface HttpMessageWriter<T> {

// ...

    Mono<Void> write(Publisher<? extends T> inputStream, ResolvableType elementType,
            @Nullable MediaType mediaType, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage message, Map<String, Object> hints);
```

When you begin to implement that `write()` method, you quickly realize you can't. When you invoke `subscribe()` on that `inputStream`, you discover that the type of the element you are supposed to consume is `<lambda parameter>`, and you can do *literally nothing* with a `<lambda parameter>`, even cast it to `Object`

```java
MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.builder(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/")).build();

Mono<Void> mono = response.writeTo(exchange, new ServerResponse.Context() {
    @Override
    public List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> messageWriters() {
        return List.of(new HttpMessageWriter<>() {
            @Override
            public List<MediaType> getWritableMediaTypes() {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean canWrite(ResolvableType elementType, MediaType mediaType) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> write(Publisher<?> inputStream, ResolvableType elementType,
                                    MediaType mediaType, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage message,
                                    Map<String, Object> hints) {
                inputStream.subscribe(body -> /* you can do nothing with "body"! */);
                return Mono.empty();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
});
```

I guess it stems from the fact that the generic type never gets resolved to anything, though I'm unsure why javac is not convinced it's *at least an `Object`*

I post this question mainly to get help in wrapping my head around it. It seems so twisted to me

My specific question is: **Why does it happen, and is it really impossible to implement the `ServerResponse.Context` interface?**

Comment: You're aware that you can't pass a lambda to `Publisher.subscribe` anyway, because `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber` isn't a functional interface?

Comment: @tgdavies you got me there

Comment: I think you just need to understand what the `Subscriber` interface is.

Comment: @tgdavies I kind of understand (I debugged, I know that Reactor wraps my consumers in `LambdaSubscriber`s, that it implements Reactive Streams), but I can't say it's *really* the point. You can see [this update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78054404/4), I implemented it, but it looks awful